# Where to put "be" in this question?

Tags: grammar

Which of the following sentences grammatically and meaningfully correct?

> what would the necessary and sufficient conditions for the
>   distribution of A be the same as B?

or

> what would be the necessary and sufficient conditions for the
>   distribution of A the same as B?

Comment: Are you asking what conditions would make A the *same* as B?

Comment: @Fivesideddice yes

Answer (score 2):

Neither is correct. ‘Be’ has to be used twice or it doesn’t sound natural, as in

> ‘What would the necessary and sufficient conditions be for the distribution of A to be the same as B?’

or

> ‘What would be the necessary and sufficient conditions for the distribution of A to be the same as B?’

This is because you’re using the verb ‘to be’ to refer to two different things: the conditions, and the distribution.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I agree with this answer, but there is an important point that Fivesideddice hasn't explained: why are there two different valid sentences? The answer is that normally the verb (_be_) would follow the subject (_the necessary and sufficient conditions for ... as B_) in a question, putting the "first" _be_ right at the end of the sentence. But that would be hard to understand, so [Heavy clause extraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition) allows it to come earlier, either before the long subject (Fivesideddice's second sentence) or in the middle of it (the first sentence).

Comment: However, as far as I have been taught, the general structure should be "(w-question) + (would/can/might/...) + (the subject) + (verb) + (the rest)", but in the second sentence, you are using both "would/can/might" part and "verb" part

Comment: @ColinFine Thanks for pointing out; actually, that one also something I normally do, but I usually think that was not grammatical, so thanks a lot :)